# Message: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string

Tags: php

**spreadsheet_reader.php**

Whenever I am trying to upload xls file in codeigniter using spreadshee reader library, its showing error in this function

```
function _encodeUTF16($string)
    {
        $result = $string;
        if ($this->_defaultEncoding){
            switch ($this->_encoderFunction){
                case 'iconv' :     $result = iconv('UTF-8', $this->_defaultEncoding, $string);
                                break;
                case 'mb_convert_encoding' :     $result = mb_convert_encoding($string, $this->_defaultEncoding, 'UTF-8' );
                                break;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: And …? What is your question? Do you understand what the error message _means_?

Comment: Verify, if the input (`$string`) is really UTF-8 encoded.